# How to make two same numbers and insert set.seed() and file name?

Tags: r, seed

I want to make two same numbers and insert them into set.seed() and file name as below

```
    set.seed(8888)
    write(rnorm(500),"theta_8888_g.txt", sep=",", ncol=500)
    set.seed(9999)
    write(rnorm(500),"theta_9999_g.txt", sep=",", ncol=500)
     ,,,,,,,
    set.seed(111111)
    write(rnorm(500),"theta_1111_g.txt", sep=",", ncol=500)
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

```
y <- 8888
set.seed(y)
write(rnorm(500), paste0("theta_", y, "_g.txt"), sep=",", ncol=500)
```

And for a more generalized solution, create a function:

```
write.theta <- function(x) {
  set.seed(x)
  write(rnorm(500), paste0("theta_", x, "_g.txt"), sep=",", ncol=500)
}
```

You can then

```
write.theta(8888)
```

or

```
y <- c(8888, 9999, 1111)
sapply(y, write.theta)
```